# How can I pass an object I wrote into a constructor of another class?

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am implementing a Duplicator class that will allow me to duplicate Game objects. I need to be able to create an identical Game object to the one I have. This is exists within a larger implementation of a board game with several other classes such as Board and Space.

I have two files for the Duplicator class:

**Duplicator.h**

```
#ifndef DUPLICATOR_H
#define DUPLICATOR_H

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <stack>
#include "Game.h"

using namespace Rcpp;


class Duplicator {
private:
  Game gameObj = Game(5);
public:
  Duplicator(Game g);
  // Game genDuplicate();
};
#endif
```

**Duplicator.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Game.h"
#include "Duplicator.h"

using namespace Rcpp;




Duplicator::Duplicator(Game g){
  gameObj = g;
}



RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Duplicator)
  RCPP_MODULE(duplicator_cpp) {

    class_<Duplicator>("Duplicator")
    .constructor<Game>()
    ;
```

The error I keep getting is:

> no matching constructor for initialization of 'Game'

The game class is contained in two files.

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class Game {
private:
  int id;
public:
  Game(int n);
};

#endif
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "Game.h"

using namespace Rcpp;

Game::Game(int n){
  id = n;
}


RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Game)
  RCPP_MODULE(game_cpp) {

    class_<Game>("Game")
    .constructor<int>()
    ;
  }
```

I'm not quite sure what I need to do. It seems like I need to supply a constructor for Game in the Duplicator class.

Comment: Most likely `Game` has a deleted copy constructor, due to one of several reasons why this happens in C++. Unfortunately, because your question fails to meet the requirements for a [mre], as explained in the [help], this is, at most, a guess, and nobody will be able to give you a definitive answer until you [edit] your question so that it meets all the requirements. For more information, see [ask] questions.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have updated my question to contain a minimal example for the Game class that replicates this error.

Comment: Seems like writing a copy constructor for the Game class (e.g. Game(const Game & copyMe) ) would solve the problem and also remove the new for a Duplicator class since you could then copy a Game object via e.g. Game newObj(oldObj);

Comment: Your snippet seems to be doing what you expect in terms of `Duplicator d{gameObj};` without the Rcpp parts: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c12e15ba4f44d2af 
@JeremyFriesner wouldn't the default copy ctor work as expected?

Comment: Is this in the context of an R package?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I tried to create a copy constructor as you suggested, which successfully copied the Game object, but when I change the new object the original changes as well. Do you know if I could make the new object an independent copy?

Comment: @RalfStubner yes, this is in the context of the R package.

Comment: I don't think the original changes when you change the copy.  If you are seeing that it does, that suggests that either you are misinterpreting what is happening, or what you created was not an actual copy but rather a pointer or a reference to the original Game object -- or there is some R-specific magic going on that is outside the scope of usual C++ behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(...)` to the header file, at least when you want to use that class as an argument or return type in other compilation units. Otherwise the compiler does not know that e.g. `Game` can be converted to a `SEXP` and vice versa.